# Login with Angular 6 get request

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to login to my webservice my register works good, but when I try to login it's returning me different numbers like 417, 415, randomly.

This is my post

```
login(userToLogin : UserToLogin) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/auth/login`, userToLogin)
            .pipe(map(userToLogin => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (userToLogin && userToLogin.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(userToLogin));
                }

                return userToLogin;
            }));
    }
```

The thing is that this response if it's ok should return this :

```
export class LoginToken{
    accesToken:string;
    refreshToken:string;
    tokenType:string;
    expiryDuration:number;
}
```

And UserToLogin is the requestBody that my Login requires

```
export class UserToLogin {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    deviceInfo : DeviceInfo;
    constructor(email: string, password: string, deviceInfo: DeviceInfo){
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.deviceInfo = deviceInfo;
    }
}

export class DeviceInfo {
    deviceId: string;
    deviceType: string;
    notificationToken: string;
}
```

And then I should save this in my localStorage, but I'm wondering if I have to save the user email and this as a map or something can you guide me?

My problem is that login is not successfully, I don't know what I'm missing.

### EDIT

Problem was a typo of json body but the thing is that I'm getting this error :

> POST http://localhost:9004/api/auth/login 401

Also getting the message :

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:9004/api/auth/login", ok: false, …}

The message that I'm showing is "User is disabled" but I don't know how to detect this error, ok, it goes to the error method but it's refreshing the page and the message disappears also the data disappears too.

This is my `Routes`

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "", component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
{ path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },

//otherwise redirect to home
{ path: "**", redirectTo: "" }
];
```

And my login component is :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  usertologin: UserToLogin;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ["", Validators.required],
      password: ["", Validators.required]
    });

    // reset login status
    //this.authenticationService.logout();

    // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams["returnUrl"] || "/";
  }
  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() {
    return this.loginForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.usertologin = new UserToLogin(
      this.f.username.value,
      this.f.password.value,
      this.generateRandomDeviceInfo()
    );

    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService
      .login(this.usertologin)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("RETURN IS " + JSON.stringify(data));
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.alertService.error(error);
          this.loading = false;
        }
      );
  }

  generateRandomDeviceInfo() {
    var deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo();
    deviceInfo.deviceId = "123";
    deviceInfo.deviceType = "DEVICE_TYPE_ANDROID";
    deviceInfo.notificationToken = "123";
    return deviceInfo;
  }

I can not stay in login without redirect to any page, I mean if it's error it should stay in the login page but it's refreshing even if it's error.
```

Comment: can you clarify: what is returning these random numbers? the http request or the "login" function?

Comment: Try to set `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in post request

Comment: Please check edit